# Showing that an element is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$[i]

Tags: ring-theory, factoring

Let p be a prime integer, and suppose p = a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> has NO integer solution.

The exercise asks that if p = a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> has no solution, then p is a prime in the set of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}$[i], where if α $\in \mathbb{Z}$[i], then α = a + bi, where a, b are integers.

I solved this already, but I am reading a much shorter solution:
If p = αβ, then p<sup>2</sup> = |α|<sup>2</sup> |β|<sup>2</sup>.  If |α|= 1, then α is a unit, and similarly for β.  If we want p to not be a prime, then: 
|α|<sup>2</sup> = |β|<sup>2</sup> = p, which implies p = |α|<sup>2</sup> = a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup>, which has no solution and thus p is a prime in the set of Gaussian integers.

My questions:
I'm having trouble understanding the second to last point: If α, β are not units, then why exactly does |α|<sup>2</sup> = |β|<sup>2</sup> = p? 
I'm also having trouble understanding why p<sup>2</sup> = |α|<sup>2</sup> |β|<sup>2</sup>.  I'm not sure if it's a typo in the solutions, but from my understanding I thought that we can only write |p|<sup>2</sup> = |α|<sup>2</sup> |β|<sup>2</sup>.  What let's us write p<sup>2</sup> = |α|<sup>2</sup> |β|<sup>2</sup>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we said if $|\alpha| = 1$, then $\alpha$ is a unit, right?  So that means if $\alpha$ is not a unit, then $|\alpha| \neq 1$.

So, if $p^{2} = |\alpha|^{2}|\beta|^{2}$, and both $\alpha, \beta$ are not units, then $|\alpha| \neq 1$ and $|\beta| \neq 1$, which means $|\alpha|^{2} \neq 1$ and $|\beta|^{2} \neq 1$.

But we know $$p^{2} = |\alpha|^{2} |\beta|^{2}$$

which implies $$ \underbrace{p p}_{\text{prime factorization of $p^{2}$}} = |\alpha|^{2} |\beta|^{2}$$

If both factors on the right hand side are not $1$, and $p$ is prime, then it should be clear **(if it's not clear, please comment so I can clarify)** that $|\alpha|^{2} = |\beta|^{2} = p$. (Remember that $p$ is a prime integer, and $|\alpha|, |\beta|$ are both positive integers.)

Comment: Thank you.  I just edited my post to add in a second question.  Would you be able to answer why we are able to write $p^2 = |a|^2|b|^2?$

Comment: @JamesNorton Usually, we write $|x|$ to denote the absolute value of $x$.  If $x$ is a real number, this is just the positive version of that real number.  If $x$ is of the form $a + bi$, then $|x| = (a^{2} + b^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}$.  But we said $p$ was a prime integer, which means it's a real number.  So we do technically need $|p|^{2}$ as you posed in your question, but since $p$ is an integer, we have $|p| = p$ if $p \geq 0$ or $|p| = -p$ if $p < 0$.  In either of these cases, $|p|^{2} = p^{2}$.  Again, this is because $p$ is an integer.  If $x = a + bi$, we can't say $|x|^{2} = x^{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

If the product of two natural numbers (both not $1$) is the square of a prime $p$, they obviously are both equal to $p$ by unique factorization.